# Is there a way to format a pivot table and embed it in an email in python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table dataframe (df_pivot) using the data from another dataframe. I creating df_html = df_pivot.to_html().

Then I use win32com (mail.HTMLBody = df_html) to send out an email with the pivot table in the body. This functionality is working fine.

I want to be able to format the table in the email (center align, colour the cells, etc) to look more presentable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at [`pandas.Style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) that will enable you to give *style* to your dataframe (i.e. cell colors, alignment etc.).

Once your dataframe is styled, you can use their method `render()` to collect the associated HTML, and here you go!

```
In [0]: df = pd.DataFrame([1])                                                                               

In [1]: html = df.style.set_properties(**{'background-color': 'black', 
    ...:                                  'color': 'lawngreen', 
    ...:                                  'border-color': 'white'}).render()
In [2]: print(html)                                             
Out[2]: <style type="text/css">
    #T_f804fbf6_6947_11ea_b4ca_8c8590b95ef2row0_col0 {
        background-color: black;
        color: lawngreen;
        border-color: white;
    }
</style>
<table id="T_f804fbf6_6947_11ea_b4ca_8c8590b95ef2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="blank level0"></th>
            <th class="col_heading level0 col0">0</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th id="T_f804fbf6_6947_11ea_b4ca_8c8590b95ef2level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0">0</th>
            <td id="T_f804fbf6_6947_11ea_b4ca_8c8590b95ef2row0_col0" class="data row0 col0">1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. This is working for my pivot table data frame. however, it is only formatting the columns for which I am doing the sum aggregation for. For example, if I am doing a pivot on first name, last name and want to see the sum of number of accounts in one column and sum of number of properties in another column. When I use the above, only the cells which have the sums are being formatted and nothing else (i.e. no first name, last name column, no header, etc).

Comment: You're welcome! I think `style` properties are by default applied in value cells, not index cells, indeed. You could have a look if it's possible to give style to index cells.

Comment: I am using the follow now (th for the index columns, so I can format index independently)
html = (my_data_pivot.style
        .set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('font-size', '10pt'), ('background-color', '#edeeef'), ('border-color', 'black'), ('border-style', 'solid'), ('border-width', '1px'),('border-collapse', 'collapse'), ('text-align', 'center')]}])
        .set_properties(**{'font-size': '10pt', 'background-color': '#edeeef', 'border-color': 'black', 'border-style': 'solid', 'border-width': '1px', 'border-collapse': 'collapse', 'text-align': 'center'})
        .render())